# Passing data between controllers

Tags: community

Say I have page A which uses controller X, and page B controller Y . I am fetching the Record Id  of an object named Visit from the url in controller X and this fetched Id is to be sent to controller Y which again have same  fetched Record Id from object Visit.

My requirement is to compare these Id's .once the Ids are same, i should enter the detail of page in another object called survey.

can somebody help.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 3):

We can not pass data from one controller to other controller. Only way of doing that is passing parameter using visualforce page. When you are redirecting from one page to other. You can use following code:

```
PageReference nextPage = Page.yourNextpage;
nextPage.getparameters().put('paramName','paramValue);
return nextPage;
```